# Bybit P2P API get orders

Tags: python, api, bybit

Is there a bybit p2p API , that I can use as a p2p merchant? I'm trying to build a p2p website/app using a p2p API . I'm new to programming,.. so anyone who has an idea about how to go about this , please help me out. Thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

At the moment Bybit has no API for P2P. This is confirmed by members of the Bybit community in Telegram. And there are no plans to create this API yet either. Although from a technical point of view, creating at least an elementary request for order history is not that difficult. At least they haven't even implemented a normal way to upload the history even in the regular version of the site, so I can't even guess if there will be an API.